# Cocoapods: Unable to add a source with url https://cdn.cocoapods.org/ named trunk

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

When I try to install a pod for Xcode I get the following error:

> ```
> [!] Unable to add a source with url `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` named `trunk`.
> You can try adding it manually in `/Users/chrisbuys/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
> ```

Things I have tried:

1. Restarting Computer
2. Uninstalling and Reinstalling cocoapods
3. Removing trunk and removing master
4. Updating the pod

Anyone have any idea why I can't install pods?

Thanks

Comment: what's in your Podfile? which pod won't load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocoapods CDN is currently down due to DNS issues. (see [status.cocoapods.org](https://status.cocoapods.org/) and [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10078) issue)

As a temporary workaround you can replace `source` in the top level of your `Podfile`, like this:

```
source 'https://cocoapods-cdn.netlify.app/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal and type ‘ sudo gem install cocoapods ‘ . Then type ‘ cd ‘ then drag the project file to your terminal window, press enter. Then type ‘ pod init ‘ to initialize the pod file, then type the pods you want to install, then type ‘ pod install. I hope it’s helpful